# How to get ec2 instances stopped for long time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am creating a script to find instances stopped for a long time. With below command, I am able to find the day and time when it stopped.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --filters "Name=instance-state-code,Values=80" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value, State.Name, StateTransitionReason]' --output text | sort -k 6,6
```

My task is to find the total number of day the instance is in a stopped state.

Comment: What do you intend doing once you have the time? You might be better-off writing a Python script rather than trying to massage the results from the AWS CLI.

Comment: I want to create a script which finds the servers stopped more than a month.

Comment: ...and then does what? Just lists them on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The `StateTransitionReason` field is just a text string. You'd have to manipulate it to convert it into a date, then perform some date maths on it.

It's probably easier to do it in a programming language, such as Python:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = client.describe_instances()

for r in response['Reservations']:
  for i in r['Instances']:
    if i['State']['Code'] == 80:
      transition_timestamp = datetime.strptime(i['StateTransitionReason'][16:39], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
      print (datetime.now() - transition_timestamp).days
```

However, it's not a 100% reliable field to use -- I had a stopped instance where this field was not populated.

Comment: how can I modify this code to find stopped instances older than  30 days

Comment: @cloudbug The last line shows how to obtain the number of days since the instance was 'transitioned'. Just use it in an `if` statement.

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'days'`

Comment: It prints `63 days, 15:05:50.422174` and towards end gives the above error. what is this [16:39] used in code?

Comment: Based on my comments on that answer (from 2 years ago), it seems that sometimes there is no `StateTransitionReason`. If that's the case, it isn't possible to determine when the instance was stopped. So, check whether that field is available and that it contains a date.

Comment: The `[16:39]` is probably extracting the timestamp from a text field. Take a look at the content of `StateTransitionReason` and you'll start getting an idea of what it is doing. The rest is all Python: When subtracting timestamps from each other, it turns into a `timedelta`, and the `.days()` function extracts the number of days in the timedelta.